# Sort a large folder into 3 smaller folders with lists

Tags: python, excel, list, sorting

I have a folder of over 600 files I am trying to break down into 3 smaller folders.

I have the lists of file names that need to end up in each folder, just unsure how to code this.

Looking for a simple python program to be able to sort this folder into smaller folders using the file lists I have in excel.

Feel free to reach out with questions and I will do my best to provide further detail.

Note: On Windows 10 - Python 3.6

Comment: Please provide a small workable example and your desired output. Show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read up on [what topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is not a site to ask for people to write code for you. If you are writing code and get stuck or have questions, please share and we can help out more.

Comment: Have you figured out how to do the first step, which is pulling the data from Excel into your Python program?  I suggest exporting it as CSV from Excel so you can use Python's `csv` module.  Once you've done that, just use `shutil.move` or an equivalent to move each file from its old location to its new location.